# How access parent's controls from child of child using javascript?

Tags: javascript, parent-child

I want to access controls of parent window from child of a popoup like:

- From `Window1`, `Window2` is opened
- From `Window2`, `Window3` is opened
- From `Window3`, `Window2` is opened

Now i need to access Window1's controls from Window2 in case when Window2 is opened from Window3, How can i do it?

I tried to use `window.opener.getElementById()` and `window.opener.opener.getElementById()`by i am confused here!

**EDIT:**

**Code in Window1 that opens Window2**:

```
window.open('window2');
```

**Code in Window2 that opens Window3**:

```
window.location.href = 'Window3';
```

**Code in Window3 to open Window2:**

```
window.open('window2');
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please post the actual code you are using?

Comment: How can Window2 be opened from Window3 when Window3 was opened from Window2? Do you mean that something might close Window2 and then it might be re-opened with a different parent?

Comment: Websites shouldn't open windows at all. It is bad UX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scan backwards through the `window.opener` chain:

```
function getBaseOpener(win){
  var opener;
  do {
    /// check to see if our storage property has been set, if so use it
    /// this gets around the problem that the window.opener chain may have
    /// been broken.
    if ( win.baseOpener ) {
      opener = win.baseOpener;
      break;
    }
    /// for each window.opener we find scan backwards until we find a 
    /// window that has no window.opener. This should be our main window.
  } while( (opener = win.opener) && (win = opener) );
  /// return the result and store it for next time, this will prevent
  /// problems if any of our openers are ever closed.
  return (win.baseOpener = opener);
}
```

The above should always return the base opener, as long as it is executed once on each newly opened window just after that window has been created (and the entire window chain is still alive at that point).

Obviously if the base window is ever closed you have a problem ;)

#### update

Apologies, I thought the above was clear, I guess it is if you've handled lots of intercommunication between windows -- but not if not :) Anyway, I've added comments to explain the code and added usage information to make things clearer.

Place the following so that it'll load in each of your windows that'll get opened.

```
<script>
  function getBaseOpener(win){
    var opener;
    do {
      if ( win.baseOpener ) {
        opener = win.baseOpener;
        break;
      }
    } while( (opener = win.opener) && (win = opener) );
    return (win.baseOpener = opener);
  }
  /// this first execution is important, it creates the baseOpener
  /// property that will keep our link to the main window even
  /// if our parents have been closed and reopened later on.
  var mainWindow = getBaseOpener(window);
</script>
```

Then anywhere in your code if you need to get the base window, just use the following:

```
mainWindow
```

or run getBaseOpener again:

```
getBaseOpener(window)
```

This should always return the base/main window (Window 1) - except when executed from within the base window itself... there it will return `undefined`.

If you then wish to use `getElementById` you'll need to access the document like this:

```
mainWindow.document.getElementById('element_id');
```

Comment: I tried it but it says baseOpener is `undefined' i am using IE9

Comment: @YaqubAhmad How are you using the function above? as it shouldn't return that kind of error at all... because the code is checking existence of it's properties before use. You wont be able to use `window.baseOpener` directly - if that is what you've attempted - as it isn't a native property.

Comment: Great Thanks for providing the complete solution, my first choice is to follow this solution, let me try it again.

Comment: The win.baseOpener = something not works for me. I tried it directly like window.open(...).baseOpener = window. But i can access it and it always remain `undefined` in IE9.

Answer (score 1):

since you are using a window again, **the original opener value is lost**

you must use window.name to identify windows

```
window3 > window.open(url, "window2",.....);
window1 > window.open(url, "window2",.....);
```

you can name / rename windows using

```
window.name = "window3";
```

also you can use this

```
function getOpenerWindowByName(name)
{
     var w = window;
     while(w = w.opener) if(w.name === name) return w;
     return null;
}
```

Comment: -1 This method will not work for what the OP has requested. For one, you make no mention on how the OP will reference the windows (only how to open them). Secondly this wont work for the original window (which is what the OP requested) considering it has no name. Thirdly there is no "must" in having to use a name to identify a window, JavaScript has these handy things called variables and properties, which can be used for storing references or values that might otherwise *get lost* along the way.

Comment: yes, but name is the only way to refer a opened window, if these windows changed their location

Comment: But this is not what the OP has asked. They have asked to reference only `window1 - the Main Window` from the other windows... which is entirely possible without names. It is also quite easy to reference opened windows without names by storing the returned `window object` that is created when using `window.open` - all you need is to store these for use later in some kind of look-up object. Then you just need to check the `window.closed` boolean on each object to see if/when the window has been closed.